# Showing on mouseover a div created dynamically and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched a lot through questions but I did not find the right way. My problem is: I want to create a `div` dynamically , showing it on `mouseover` appending it to another `div`, and remove (through `remove()` function) on `mouseout`. I tried couple ways but in any of them , sometimes the `div` shows up and then disappear, sometimes it doesnt, sometimes it disappear when my mouse goes away from the text in the container `div`.
Thank you guys .

#### This is my code

```
    var usr = 'username_pre';

var newdiv = $('<div>', { 
              html: '<a href="#" title="">'+usr+'</a> </br> <a href="#" title="">impostazioni</a> </br> <a href="#" title="">esci</a>'
              });


$("#container").mouseover(function(){
        $("#options").css('visibility','visible').append(newdiv);
    }); 
$("#options").mouseout(function(){
         $(newdiv).remove();
});
```

Comment: Your code is appending on mouseover `#container` but removing on mouseout from `#options` - should these perhaps be the same element? Please show a little of your html.

Comment: Hi. can u post some html code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
$("#container").mouseover(function(){
        $("#options").css('display','block').append(newdiv);
    }); 
$("#options").mouseout(function(){
    $("#options").css('display','none');
    $(newdiv).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using :

This code html :

```
  <div id="container" class="cont">
  <a href="#" id="username" class="nomeutente" title=""> Stefano Imparato </a>
  </div>
  <div id="options" >
  <a href="#" id="user" title="">usr</a> </br>
  <a href="#" title="">impostazioni</a> </br>
  <a href="#" title="">esci</a> 
  </div>
```

Code jquery :

```
$("#container").mouseover(function(){   
        $("#container").append($("#options"));
        $("#options").css({
            'display' : 'block'
        });
        $(this).find('#user').text(usr);
    });

$("#container").mouseout(function(){
    $("#options").css('display','none');
});
```

css :

```
#option { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is html :

```
<div id="container" class="cont">
<a href="#" id="username" class="nomeutente" title=""> Stefano Imparato </a>
<div id="options" class="opt"></div>
</div>
```